# Eclipse line breaks not showing in Notepad

Tags: php, eclipse

When I write code in Eclipse and then open the file in notepad there are no line breaks and I can't even read the code.  Is there a way to fix this in eclipse?  What's happening that causes this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that Eclipse is putting in UNIX line endings `\n` instead of the endings that Windows uses `\r\n`.

I think you need to look in: `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> New text file line delimiter` to reconfigure Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Chances are it's to do with Eclipse using one of CR/LF for line breaks, and if I recall correctly notepad doesn't read one of them correctly. (I can't remember which it was that notepad doesn't read)

I'd suggest using Notepad++ in place of notepad.

You could also try playing with the newline setting in Eclipse.